# How can I ensure that a specific passport is used for US immigration?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, dual-nationality

I have two passports. One (Canada) does not require a visa (or ESTA) to enter the US. The other (New Zealand) would require at least an ESTA. If I am flying to visit the US, how can I ensure that the US electronic I-94 system records my Canadian passport number, and NOT my New Zealand passport?

I understand the US electronic I-94 system gets passenger passport information from airline manifests. In this case, should I explicitly give ONLY my Canadian passport number to the airline? What if the airline already has my information, including NZ passport number, recorded from prior trips? How can I control which passport number they will give CBP?

I am assuming that the I-94 electronic record is created when I present a passport to US immigration, but I'm unclear on exactly how it gets cleared when I leave.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give them your Canadian passport.

From the US point of view, whichever one you travel on is the one you'll be using and therefore, your citizenship.

Example: I have New Zealand and South African, and travelled through the US on my New Zealand.  Never need to mention the South African one - there's never a question about it, apart from some forms asking your place of birth.

You provide the passport to the airline for this trip - they'll ask again.  You could have a new NZ passport by now, or a different citizenship, so they're always going to ask again.

Comment: I assume by "them" you mean the airline. I suppose it isn't relevant today, since (AFAIK) only the US checks the passenger manifest from the airline, but it could potentially become complicated if *two* countries both checked the passenger manifests for immigration purposes and somebody wanted to (or was required to) use different passports for each country.

Comment: By them, I meant anyone who asks for it :)  But yes, the airline, travel agent, border - heck, don't even bother taking your NZ one with you, aside from for getting back into NZ (smart gate for the win!)